# Reordering column names in R with the use of a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I could not find another question about my problem although a lot with similar title exist. So, I have a matrix 1000x200 with chemical compounds as column names. For some reason I want to reorder my compounds based on a two dimensional array that matches compound names with Compound IDs. For example:

```
Compound    CID
Ramipril    5362129
Eliprodil   60703
artesunate  5464098
benzonatate 7699
```

But in my data set is:

```
    benzonatate   Ramipril  Eliprodil  Artesunate
1   0.453         0.332     0.897      0.123
```

The desired output should be a matrix with columns ordered as in the two dimensional vector:

```
    Ramipril   Eliprodil Artesunate benzonatate  
1   0.332      0.897     0.123      0.453
```

Is there a way that I can match the names with CIDs and in the same time and then reorder the matrix columns?

Comment: Your description `matrix 1000x200 with chemical compounds as column names` and the data showed is not matching.  For example, in the second dataset, the column names are `X.1`, `X.2`.  I am guessing that you read the dataset with `header=FALSE`, so the column names are automatically created and the original column names became the first row.  I posted a solution based on the example posted.

Comment: Hi akrun. Thanks for your answer and comment. I will try it. You are wright, I shouldn't use X.1 on the example so I will edit it. My column names are the one stated. I used (wrongly) X.1 etc to declare the 1st column etc. The column names are the names of the chemicals, here I only use 4 of the 200 just as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I included both cases, so probably it should work for you.

Comment: Looks like in the example, `artesunate` in the first dataset  and `Artesunate` as column names in the second.  Do you have cases like these?

Comment: I think your example should work.  I `match`ed the column of 'df1' with the column names of 'df2' after changing both to uppercase so that even if there is a mismatch as I mentioned above, it should now match.

Comment: Actually yes. That was quite a problem. Also some of the compound names are numbers and some others are written inside quotation marks. So, in brief I have characters, numbers and characters inside brackets for names of the compounds.

Comment: I'll try it and I will do that. I also think it should work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `match` to get the index for reordering the second dataset ('df2') based on the 'Compound' column of first dataset ('df1'). Eventhough, the OP mentioned a `matrix` as the first dataset, it might be better to use `data.frame` for columns that have mixed classes.

```
 df2[,match(toupper(df1[, 'Compound']), toupper(colnames(df2)), nomatch=0)]
 #  Ramipril Eliprodil Artesunate benzonatate
 #1    0.332     0.897      0.123       0.453
```

---

Using another example, where I created 'm2' as a `matrix` with column names as chemical compounds,

```
m2N <- m2[,match(toupper(df1N[,'Compound']), toupper(colnames(m2)), nomatch=0)]
m2N 
#     Ramipril Eliprodil artesunate benzonatate
#[1,]        6         1          3           3
#[2,]        4         6          2           2
#[3,]        7         7          4           7
#[4,]        7         1          1           5
#[5,]        3         2         10           7
#[6,]        9         7          2          10
#[7,]        2         0          8           3
#[8,]        0         6          6           8
#[9,]        5         6          7           8
#[10,]       1         0         10           2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Compound = c("Ramipril", "Eliprodil", "artesunate", 
"benzonatate"), CID = c(5362129L, 60703L, 5464098L, 7699L)),
.Names = c("Compound", 
"CID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(benzonatate = 0.453, Ramipril = 0.332, 
 Eliprodil = 0.897, 
Artesunate = 0.123), .Names = c("benzonatate", "Ramipril", 
"Eliprodil", "Artesunate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

#### newdata

```
df1N <- structure(list(Compound = c("Ramipril", "Eliprodil", "Stargazer", 
"artesunate", "benzonatate", "Ronipril"), CID = c(5362129L, 60703L, 
7859L, 5464098L, 7699L, 7892L)), .Names = c("Compound", "CID"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

set.seed(24)
m2  <- matrix(sample(0:10, 4*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=4, 
  dimnames=list(NULL, c('benzonatate', 'Ramipril', 'Eliprodil', 'artesunate')))
```

Comment: I edited the description so I think now it makes more sense. I will try your solution and get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The 1st worked fine. I had some mismatches apparently that were messing up my tries to reorder but I dealt with them. Thank you so much for your replies.